# PC Not Booting on First Power Button Click

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply

Recently built a new desktop. Has had this issue since day one where the power button will not cause a boot the first try. I end up having to hold it down and pray it turns on each time. I took some troubleshooting steps already: tested headers by jumping MOBO which saw the issue continue to persist even when jumping the board itself, I tested the power supply using the 16/17 24 pin method and found that the PSU fans worked properly as they should. Those two tests were all I could think of for seeing what the issue could be. At this point I’m just clueless. If anyone has a possible troubleshooting tip let me know

Comment: Do you have another PSU around? Or at least another desktop computer? Swapping the PSU can help understanding whether the problem is related to this component.

Comment: Any warranty?  .